# Finalizar ejecución en try-catch

Tags: java, try-catch

Quiero saber cómo puedo hacer que la ejecución de un proceso termine si se recoge una excepción dentro de este método o dentro de algún submétodo que contenga.

```
// Si capturo una excepcion aqui o en sub_metodo_1(), quiero que termine la ejecución y NO se ejecute sub_metodo_2();
try {
  ...
  sub_metodo_1();
  sub_metodo_2();
catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Cuando te salta una excepción en un trozo de código encerrado en un `try-catch`, ahí donde se produce, salta la ejecución y no continúa. Si `sub_metodo_1` produce una excepción, `sub_metodo_2` no se ejecutará nunca. Así que lo que tendrías que hacer es lo que sea que hagas para terminar tu programa, dentro del `catch`. Sin más.

Comment: El código que tengo no hace eso, salta la excepcion, se captura, pero el padre sigue con su ejecucion y ejecuta los siguientes subprocesos.

Comment: No será que estás capturando la excepción dentro de sub_metodo_1? Entonces sub_metodo_1 no seguiría su ejecución, pero saldría de la función con la excepción ya procesada y claro que ejecutaría sub_metodo_2.

Comment: Claro, concretamente estoy haciendo INSERTS dentro de una base de datos SQL, y dentro de sub_metodo_1 capturo las SQLException. Entonces, segun lo que dices, ¿estas capturas deberían ser en la clase padre, pese a que el insert lo hace el subproceso?

Comment: Si metes el código en un try-catch, ahí se captura la excepción, y en ningún otro sitio. Así que tendrá que capturarla ahí donde necesites, según tu lógica. También puedes capturar no con Exception genérico, sino  clases de excepción específicas. Para la base de datos unas y sino, el padre capturaría las más genéricas. Depende de tu diseño.

Comment: Mmm vale creo que entendí, muchas gracias por tus respuestas :)

Comment: De acuerdo a lo que comentas, puedes hacer que tus métodos sub_metodo_1() y sub_metodo_2() arrojen las excepciones en vez de controlarlas... Ocupándo la cláusula throws. Haciéndolo así, la excepción producida en el método1 será capturada dentro del try-catch que la llama, y como se menciona arriba, ya no se ejecutará el método 2...